# What's the timing for the fish cooking minigame?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

Big the Cat has a cooking minigame where you can grill fish to earn tokens. The description says to pay attention to the music and the meat's color to cook perfectly for the most tokens, but I seem to struggle with the timing.

What is the correct timing to stop cooking fish to earn the most tokens?

[image: BBQ Spit instructions]